# qt QDeclarativeListProperty add item from qml application

Tags: qt, qml

is there any why to add item to QDeclarativeListProperty from qml file at run time?
in a loop, for example:

`var i;

for(i = 0 ; i < 100 ; ++i)

{
    listOfItems.append(MyItem {text:"list"+i})

}`

and listOfItems is the QDeclarativeListProperty list...
i don't want to do that:

```
    listOfItems:     
   [               
        MyItem{text:"list val1"},
        MyItem{text:"list val2"},       
         ......
   ]
```

i display this list in qml and the data for the list comes from qt object....

Answer (score 2):

You can't, `QDeclarativeListProperty` (or `QQmlListProperty` in Qt5) is affected only once, at instanciation time, you can't append/remove any element in it after that.

More, in JavaScript code, you can't use the `Class { }`  syntax form, it's QML specific.

Comment: If you want to create new QML objects from JS imperative code, you must use the `Qt.createComponent()` method, but any way you will not be able to affect the created object to a list property.

Comment: Maybe if you need a list of items, first create the component with the right method, and then add a reference to this item into a 'var' property which can contain a Js Array, so you can .push(myitem) in it.

Comment: If you need this array to be C++ side, you will need some QVariantList tricky things, so think about it if you really need this conception or if you can do another which is a lot more simple.

Answer (score 0):

If I get your problem right you are looking for the Component.onCompleted signal

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/main-snapshot/qml-component.html#onCompleted-signal